# EMFILE: too many open files, open BUNYAN or WINSTON

Tags: node.js, winston, bunyan

I use [Bunyan](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan) then I try [Winston](https://github.com/winstonjs) and I got same result that it says

> EMFILE: too many open files, open

So that I understand that I am doing something wrong. What I try to test is

```
var winston = require('winston');

setInterval(function(){

var logger1 = new (winston.Logger)({
       level: 'info',
    transports: [
      new (winston.transports.Console)({ level: 'error' }),
      new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: './logs/1.log', level: 'error' })
    ]
});

var logger2 = new (winston.Logger)({
       level: 'info',
    transports: [
      new (winston.transports.Console)({ level: 'error' }),
      new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: './logs/2.log', level: 'error' })
    ]
});

logger1.error('Hello logs1');
logger2.error('Hello logs2');

}, 50);
```

Note: This is only a test. I put the loggers creation in setInterval for testing. How to make it work ?

**What I want is**

```
Create logger1
Dispose logger1
Create logger2
Dispose logger2
Create logger1
Dispose logger1
Create logger1
Dispose logger1
```

...

**What it is now I think**

```
Create logger1
Create logger2
Create logger1
Create logger2
Create logger1
Create logger2
```

...

Comment: A logger is generally created just once during the lifetime of an application. What _actual_ problem are you trying to solve? JS doesn't have destructors so there is no _"Dispose"_ trigger.

Answer (score 0):

## **EMFILE: too many open files (with Winston v3.2.1)**

> As you create a winston instance, it will open the file and never
> close it until logger instance exist. **Close()** function worked like a
> champ. We need to use **close()** function to remove instance of winston.

```
   logger.close();
```

---

## In you case you need to include two extra lines in your code.

```
logger1.error('Hello logs1');
logger1.close();

logger2.error('Hello logs2');
logger2.close();
```